# Вводное слово "к сожалению" в конце предложения

Tags: пунктуация

Следует ли выделять запятой "к сожалению" в конце предложения?

*У нас с тобой мало времени, к сожалению.*

Answer (score 4):

Нужно, это вводное слово выделяется всегда, независимо от места

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Запятая нужна. Ввводные слова всегда обособляются. Не путать с существительным. Например:
К сожалению добавилось чувство досады.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, нужна, так как это вводное слово, обозначающее различные чувства. Обособляется запятой, потому что находится в конце предложения, а также и в начале, и в конце.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.